# Função ponto na calculadora (números quebrados)

Tags: java

Criei uma calculadora com Swing e awt.event, e tenho ***três*** dúvidas !

**Primeira dúvida:** para criar a calculadora eu usei o import com import.javax.swing.* e java.awt.event.*, quando eu uso o *, eu estou utilizando todos os conteúdos do pacote que viriam a seguir do "" ? pois em alguns casos vi pessoas utilizando apenas javax.swing.jframe, e queria saber se o * é para usar todas as classes que viriam após ele.

As **últimas duas duvidas** são parecidas, pois bem, toda a calculadora funciona perfeitamente com exceção do botão "." para adicionar números quebrados (como 1.5 + 1.5) quando eu faço uma conta com o botão, ele ignora o botão e por exemplo 1.5+1.5, ao invés de se tornar 3, se torna 30, pois ele soma 15+15, entendem ? Em um fórum me mandaram fazer isso:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JButton n1;
    private JButton n2;
    private JButton n3;
    private JButton n4;
    private JButton n5;
    private JButton n6;
    private JButton n7;
    private JButton n8;
    private JButton n9;
    private JButton n0;
    private JButton botaoMais;
    private JButton botaoMenos;
    private JButton botaoVezes;
    private JButton botaoDividi;
    private JButton botaoIgual;
    private JButton botaoC;
    private JButton botaoCE;
    private JButton botaoPonto;
    private char operacao;
    private int inteiro;
    private int decimal;
    private double memoria;
    private boolean ponto;
    private JTextField campo;

    public Calculadora(){
        this.setTitle("Calculadora do Ozzy");
        this.setBounds(0,0,280,380);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        inteiro = 0;
        decimal = 0;
        memoria = 0;

        n1 = new JButton ();
        n1.setText("1");
        n1.setBounds(25,115,45,45);
        this.add(n1);

        n2 = new JButton ();
        n2.setText("2");
        n2.setBounds(85,115,45,45);
        this.add(n2);

        n3 = new JButton();
        n3.setText("3");
        n3.setBounds(140,115,45,45);
        this.add(n3);

        n4 = new JButton();
        n4.setText ("4");
        n4.setBounds (25,170,45,45);
        this.add(n4);

        n5 = new JButton ();
        n5.setText("5");
        n5.setBounds(85,170,45,45);
        this.add (n5);

        n6 = new JButton();
        n6.setText("6");
        n6.setBounds(140,170,45,45);
        this.add(n6);

        n7 = new JButton ();
        n7.setText("7");
        n7.setBounds(25,225,45,45);
        this.add(n7);

        n8 = new JButton();
        n8.setText("8");
        n8.setBounds (85,225,45,45);
        this.add (n8);

        n9 = new JButton ();
        n9.setText("9");
        n9.setBounds (140,225,45,45);
        this.add (n9);

        n0 = new JButton();
        n0.setText ("0");
        n0.setBounds (140,280,45,45);
        this.add (n0);

        botaoMais = new JButton();
        botaoMais.setText("+");
        botaoMais.setBounds(195,115,45,45);
        this.add(botaoMais);

        botaoMenos = new JButton ();
        botaoMenos.setText ("-");
        botaoMenos.setBounds(195,170,45,45);
        this.add (botaoMenos);

        botaoVezes = new JButton();
        botaoVezes.setText ("x");
        botaoVezes.setBounds(195,225,45,45);
        this.add(botaoVezes);

        botaoDividi = new JButton();
        botaoDividi.setText("÷");
        botaoDividi.setBounds(195,280,45,45);
        this.add(botaoDividi);

        botaoIgual = new JButton();
        botaoIgual.setText("=");
        botaoIgual.setBounds(25,280,45,45);
        this.add(botaoIgual);

        botaoPonto = new JButton ();
        botaoPonto.setText(".");
        botaoPonto.setBounds(85,280,45,45);
        this.add (botaoPonto);

        botaoC = new JButton ();
        botaoC.setText("C");
        botaoC.setBounds(25,65,105,40);
        this.add(botaoC);

        botaoCE = new JButton ();
        botaoCE.setText("CE");
        botaoCE.setBounds(140,65,100,40);
        this.add(botaoCE);

        campo = new JTextField();
        campo.setBounds(25,25,216,30);
        this.add(campo);

        n1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                if(ponto){
                    decimal +=1;
                }
                inteiro *= 10;
                inteiro +=1;
                campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "1");

            }
        });
        n2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                if (ponto){
                    decimal +=2;
                }
                inteiro *=10;
                inteiro+= 2;
                campo.setText (campo.getText()+"2");
            }
        });
        n3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                if (ponto){
                    decimal+=3;
                }
                inteiro *= 10;
                inteiro += 3;
                campo.setText(campo.getText()+"3");

            }
        });
        n4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                if (ponto){
                    decimal+=4;
                }
                inteiro *= 10;
                inteiro +=4;
                campo.setText (campo.getText ()+"4");

            }
        });
        n5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
                if (ponto){
                    decimal +=5;
                }
                inteiro*= 10;
                inteiro +=5;
                campo.setText (campo.getText ()+ "5");
            }
        });
        n6.addActionListener (new ActionListener (){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
                if (ponto){
                    decimal +=6;
                }
                inteiro*= 10;
                inteiro +=6;
                campo.setText (campo.getText ()+ "6");
            }
        });
        n7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
                if(ponto){
                    decimal +=7;
                }
                inteiro*= 10;
                inteiro +=7;
                campo.setText (campo.getText()+"7");
            }
        });
        n8.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                if(ponto){
                    decimal +=8;
                }
                inteiro *=10;
                inteiro +=8;
                campo.setText(campo.getText()+"8");
            }
        });
        n9.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                if (ponto){
                    decimal +=9;
                }
                inteiro *=10;
                inteiro +=9;
                campo.setText(campo.getText()+"9");

            }
        });
        n0.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                if(ponto){
                    decimal +=0;
                }
                inteiro*=10;
                inteiro +=0;
                campo.setText(campo.getText()+"0");
            }
        });
        botaoMais.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                double numero =Double.parseDouble(String.format("%s.%s",inteiro,decimal));
                operacao = '+';
                if (memoria > 0){
                    memoria += numero;
                }else{
                        memoria = numero;
                    }
                inteiro = 0;
                numero = 0;
                decimal = 0;
                ponto = false;
                campo.setText("");
                }
            });
        botaoMenos.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                double numero = Double.parseDouble (String.format("%s.%s",inteiro,decimal));
                operacao = '-';
                if (memoria > 0){
                    memoria -= numero;
                }else {
                    memoria = numero;
                }
                numero = 0;
                inteiro = 0;
                decimal = 0;
                ponto = false;
                campo.setText("");
            }
        });
        botaoVezes.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                double numero = Double.parseDouble (String.format("%s.%s",inteiro,decimal));
                operacao = '*';
                if (memoria > 0){
                    memoria *= numero;
                }else {
                    memoria = numero;
                }
                numero = 0;
                inteiro =0;
                decimal =0;
                ponto = false;      
                campo.setText("");
            }
        });
        botaoDividi.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
                double numero = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%s.%s",inteiro,decimal));
                operacao = '/';
                if(memoria >0){
                    memoria /=numero;
                }else {
                    memoria = numero;
                }
                numero=0;
                inteiro =0;
                decimal = 0;
                ponto = false;
                campo.setText("");
            }
        });
        botaoC.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
                inteiro = 0;
                decimal = 0;
                memoria = 0;
                ponto = false;
                campo.setText("");
            }
        });
        botaoCE.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
                inteiro = 0;
                decimal = 0;
                memoria = 0;
                ponto = false;
                campo.setText("");
            }
        });
        botaoPonto.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
                if (!ponto){
                    campo.setText(inteiro +".");
                    ponto = (true);
                }
            }
        });
        botaoIgual.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                double numero = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%s.%s", inteiro, decimal));
                switch (operacao){
                case '+':{
                    memoria += numero;
                    break;
                }
                case '-':{
                    memoria -=numero;
                    break;
                }
                case '*':{
                    memoria *=numero;
                    break;
                }
                case '/':{
                    memoria /=numero;
                    break;
                }
                }
                numero = 0;
                campo.setText(""+ memoria);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Calculadora cCalculadora = new Calculadora();
            cCalculadora.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Leitura é a variável `double` para os números que dou entrada na calculadora, e toda vez que eu entrava com um numero como 9, ao apertar o ponto virava "9.0" e isso atrapalhava a conta, mas depois que coloquei (`int`), isso deixou de ocorrer.

Eu estou dizendo que nesse campo, nesse botão, e nesse momento, leitura deixara de ser `double` para ser `int` ? E como eu faço para meu ponto funcionar e deixar de ser ignorado como disse acima ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você faz:

```
import javax.swing.*
```

Significa que você vai importar todas as classes desse pacote. Não há nada de errado nisso, até o momento que você tiver conflitos de nomes de classe, por exemplo, se você quiser usar o `Date` do `java.util.Date` e alguma classe do pacote `java.sql`, que por sua vez possui uma classe `java.sql.Date` mas que você não sabe da existência dela. Se você decidiu fazer:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.*;
```

e depois em algum ponto do seu código você usar a classe `Date` qual das duas estará sendo chamada?

```
Date d = new Date(); //java.util.Date ou java.sql.Date está sendo usada aqui?
```

Além disso, escrever o nome completo da classe que está sendo importada, ou seja pacote + classe torna mais fácil a leitura do código posteriormente, pois só de bater o olho no cabeçalho se sabe exatamente quais as classes foram importadas.

É bom lembrar que se existir algum outro nível dentro do pacote suas classes não serão automaticamente importadas.

**EDIÇÃO**

Como seu código estava incompleto eu fiz algumas suposições que não eram verdades, vendo agora pude identificar corretamente os problemas, vamos lá:

Você armazena em uma variável que será feita a conta toda vez que aperta um número ou o ponto (eu faria diferente, mas blz). Portanto, do mesmo jeito que você faz a parte das dezenas:

```
leitura *= 10;
leitura += 2; //supondo que apertou o botão dois
```

você deve fazer a separação da parte inteira para a parte decimal.

A partir do momento que você colocou um ponto, você não mais fará `leitura *= 10`, correto? Pois a parte inteira já foi definida. O meio mais simples que consegui imaginar para sair disso é você separar a sua variável `leitura` em duas, ficará uma para aquilo que é inteiro (o que está antes do ponto) e outra para aquilo que é fração (o que está depois do ponto), ficaria assim:

```
private int inteiro;
private int decimal;
private double memoria;
private boolean ponto;
```

Perceba que além de tirar o `leitura` e colocar duas variáveis em seu lugar ainda adicionei a variável `ponto`, que servirá quando o botão ponto foi pressionado e poder separar aquilo que é inteiro daquilo que é decimal:

```
botaoPonto.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){
        if(!ponto) { //olha que legal, não da mais para colocar mais de um ponto
            campo.setText(inteiro +".");
            ponto = true;
        }
    }
});
n1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        if(ponto) {
            decimal += 1;
        }
        else {
            inteiro *= 10;
            inteiro +=1;
        }
        campo.setText(campo.getText()+ "1");
    }
});
```

Para somar você deve compor um numero double com a parte inteira e a decimal que você leu:

```
botaoMais.addActionListener (new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        operacao = '+';
        //aqui é onde você compoe seu numero double
        double numero = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%s.%s", inteiro, decimal));
        if (memoria > 0){
            memoria += numero;
        }else{
            memoria = numero;
        }
        numero = 0;
        inteiro = 0;
        decimal= 0;
        ponto = false;
        campo.setText("");
    }
});
```

Dentro do seu botão igual você deve fazer a mesma composição do número double:

```
botaoIgual.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
        double numero = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%s.%s", inteiro, decimal));
```

E não se esqueça de limpar o ponto (setá-lo `false`) quando apertar CE ou C.

**Format()**

O `format()` simula o `System.out.printf()` que por sua vez foi inspirado no `printf()` do `C`.

Ele tem a função de formatar uma String de acordo com os argumentos passados. Como primeiro argumento se passa a String que será editada junto os placeholders, os demais argumentos são os valores que substituirão os placeholders da String do primeiro argumento. Exemplo:

```
System.out.printf("A soma dos números é %s", 5 + 5);
```

Retorna:

> A soma dos números é 10

O resultado da soma foi colocado no lugar do `%s`. Também seria possível colocar `%d`, que é o placeholder para números inteiros (na base 10), entretanto eu os tratei como Strings.

Uma lista completa dos placeholders:

> Symbol Description
>   %b Boolean
>   %c Character
>   %d Decimal integer (signed)
>   %e Floating point number in scientific format
>   %f Floating point numer in decimal format
>   %g Floating point numer in decimal or scientific format (depending on the
>   value passed as argument)
>   %h Hashcode of the passed argument
>   %n Line separator (new line character)
>   %o Integer formatted as an octal value
>   %s String
>   %t Date/time
>   %x Integer formatted as an hexadecimal value

Referência: [String - format() (Java Platform SE7)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Comment: Deveria adicionar esse comando no botão de igual ? Não compreendi mt bem, mas copiei o meu código inteiro aqui, espero que ajude vocês a me ajudarem ! Se não está muito fácil a compreensão me avisem !

Comment: Quem votou contra poderia me informar onde está errado? Ou reconsiderar o voto depois da edição?

Comment: Bom meu amigo, o programa rodou bem, o Eclipse não apontou erro algum, no entanto o mesmo problema persiste, a calculadora esta "ignorando" o ponto, porem dessa vez de forma parcial ! Está calculando o que vem depois do ponto, mas ao mesmo tempo ainda le o numero como um só, como se o ponto nao existisse ! como por exemplo numa conta como 1.50 + 1.50, o resultado da 301.0 (faz 150+150, e ainda conta o .50, adicionando +1 !) Não estou entendendo como isso está acontecendo ! Alguma dica ? E muito obrigado pela ajuda até aqui, ajudou demais cara !

Comment: PS: se puder também me explicar o significado de "%s.%s" eu nao entendi o significado disso ! Obrigado !

Comment: @GabrielOzzy basicamente faltou um `else` dentro do seu ActionListener de cada botão referente a um numero. Vou adicionar o detalhe do `format` na resposta.

Comment: Perfeitamente funcionando, @Math, muito obrigado cara ! Ajudou demais, lhe devo uma meu amigo, obrigado por ajudar um iniciante ! Haha =]

Answer (score 3):

Sobre o import tem uma apostila da Caelum que trata disso:

> É possível "importar um pacote inteiro" (todas as classes do pacote, exceto os subpacotes) através do coringa *:
>
> `import java.util.*;`
>
> Importar todas as classes de um pacote não implica em perda de performance em tempo de execução, mas pode trazer problemas com classes de mesmo nome! Além disso, importar de um em um é considerado boa prática, pois facilita a leitura para outros programadores. Uma IDE como o Eclipse já vai fazer isso por você, assim como a organização em diretórios.

link da apostila: http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-orientacao-objetos/pacotes-organizando-suas-classes-e-bibliotecas/#12-3-import

E sobre o seu problema com os números, eu fiz algo assim tratando os dígitos adicionados como `String` e na hora de obter da tela fazer um parse da seguinte maneira:

```
    String str = "12.3";
    float f = Float.parseFloat(str);
```

caso sejam apenas 2 números a serem somados talvez armazenar e converter duas variáveis strings seja o suficiente, e ai mostrar as mesmas na tela e realizar os cálculos, mas se tiver mais você pode usar um array de Strings com alguma estrutura de repetição, fica a seu critério.

Comment: Não consegui entender bem cara, mas pelo que eu entendi, nao funcionou pois meus números estão em double ! Ainda não consegui fazer funcionar, mas copiei todo o código aqui, se ajudar vocês a me ajudarem ! kk =]