# Como fazer operações matemáticas básicas?

Tags: java, swing

Estou desenvolvendo uma calculadora em Java para um trabalho de faculdade em que seja possível fazer as quatro operações básicas (adição, subtração, multiplicação e divisão), além de raiz quadrada e quadrado de um número, mas por enquanto eu só consegui fazer a calculadora somar os números, não estou conseguindo fazer os métodos das outras operações funcionarem.

Gostaria que alguém pudesse me orientar e mostrar onde estou errando para fazer certo.

Segue código abaixo:

```
public class CalculadoraSwing extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JButton btUm,
                btDois,
                btTres,
                btQuatro,
                btCinco,
                btSeis,
                btSete,
                btOito,
                btNove,
                btZero;

private JButton btMais,
                btMenos,
                btVezes,
                btDividido,
                btRaiz,
                btQuadrado,
                btIgual,
                btClear;                


private JTextField display;
private int leitura;
private int memoria;
private String operacao;

public CalculadoraSwing() {

    this.setTitle("Exemplo Botão Somar");
    this.setBounds(0, 0, 310, 330);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    display = new JTextField();
    display.setBounds(25, 25, 245, 30);
    this.add(display);


    //------------OPERADORES-------------
    btMais = new JButton("+");
    btMais.setBounds(175, 70, 45, 45);
    this.add(btMais);

    btMenos = new JButton();
    btMenos.setText("-");
    btMenos.setBounds(225, 70, 45, 45);
    this.add(btMenos);

    btVezes = new JButton();
    btVezes.setText("*");
    btVezes.setBounds(175, 120, 45, 45);
    this.add(btVezes);

    btDividido = new JButton();
    btDividido.setText("/");
    btDividido.setBounds(225, 120, 45, 45);
    this.add(btDividido);

    btRaiz = new JButton();
    btRaiz.setText("√");
    btRaiz.setBounds(175, 170, 45, 45);
    this.add(btRaiz);

    btQuadrado = new JButton();
    btQuadrado.setText("x²");
    btQuadrado.setBounds(225, 170, 45, 45);
    this.add(btQuadrado);


    btIgual = new JButton();
    btIgual.setText("=");
    btIgual.setBounds(175, 220, 45, 45);
    this.add(btIgual);

    btClear = new JButton();
    btClear.setText("C");
    btClear.setBounds(225, 220, 45, 45);
    this.add(btClear);


    //------------NUMERICOS-------------
    btUm = new JButton();
    btUm.setText("1");
    btUm.setBounds(25, 70, 45, 45);
    this.add(btUm);

    btDois = new JButton();
    btDois.setText("2");
    btDois.setBounds(75, 70, 45, 45);
    this.add(btDois);

    btTres = new JButton();
    btTres.setText("3");
    btTres.setBounds(125, 70, 45, 45);
    this.add(btTres);

    btQuatro = new JButton();
    btQuatro.setText("4");
    btQuatro.setBounds(25, 120, 45, 45);
    this.add(btQuatro);

    btCinco = new JButton();
    btCinco.setText("5");
    btCinco.setBounds(75, 120, 45, 45);
    this.add(btCinco);

    btSeis = new JButton();
    btSeis.setText("6");
    btSeis.setBounds(125, 120, 45, 45);
    this.add(btSeis);

    btSete = new JButton();
    btSete.setText("7");
    btSete.setBounds(25, 170, 45, 45);
    this.add(btSete);

    btOito = new JButton();
    btOito.setText("8");
    btOito.setBounds(75, 170, 45, 45);
    this.add(btOito);

    btNove = new JButton();
    btNove.setText("9");
    btNove.setBounds(125, 170, 45, 45);
    this.add(btNove);

    btZero = new JButton();
    btZero.setText("0");
    btZero.setBounds(25, 220, 145, 45);
    this.add(btZero);


    btMais.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            operacao = "+";
            memoria += leitura;
            leitura = 0;
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

    btMenos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            operacao = "-";
            memoria -= leitura;
            leitura = 0;
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

    btVezes.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            operacao = "*";
            memoria *= leitura;
            leitura = 0;
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

    btDividido.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            operacao = "/";
            memoria /= leitura;
            leitura = 0;
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

   btRaiz.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            operacao = "√";
            Math.pow(Double.valueOf(memoria),2);
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

    btQuadrado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            operacao = "x²";
            Math.sqrt(Double.valueOf(memoria));
            display.setText("");
        }
    }); 

    btIgual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            switch (operacao) {
            case "+":
                memoria += leitura;
                break;

            case "-":
                memoria -= leitura;
                break;

            case "*":
                memoria *= leitura;
                break;

            case "/":
                memoria /= leitura;
                break;

            case "x²":
               Math.pow(Double.valueOf(memoria),2);
               break;

            case "√":
                Math.sqrt(Double.valueOf(memoria));
                break;
           }
            leitura = 0;
            display.setText("" + memoria);

        }

    });

    btClear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             memoria = 0;
             leitura = 0;
            display.setText("");
        }
    });

    btUm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 1;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "1");
        }
    });

    btDois.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 2;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "2");
        }
    });

    btTres.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 3;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "3");
        }
    });

    btQuatro.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 4;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "4");
        }
    });

    btCinco.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 5;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "5");
        }
    });

    btSeis.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 6;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "6");
        }
    });

    btSete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 7;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "7");
        }
    });

    btOito.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 8;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "8");
        }
    });

    btNove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 9;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "9");
        }
    });

    btZero.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            leitura *= 10;
            leitura += 0;
            display.setText(display.getText() + "0");
        }
    });

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CalculadoraSwing exemplo = new CalculadoraSwing();
    exemplo.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Bem vindo a Stack Overflow em Português, vulgo SOpt, Sugiro que explique melhor sua duvida, seja mais especifico quanto a sua dificuldade, explique onde está errando o quê deseja fazer e o que está acontecendo quando tenta, assim fica mais fácil para que alguém lhe forneça uma possível solução

Comment: Valeu pela sugestão Rodrigo, Vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: Tem muito erro aí, tá difícil juntar todos para por numa resposta. 1) Ao pressionar a tecla de `*` ou o `/` você já faz a conta logo de cara, mas uma das variáveis é zero, então você multiplica por zero, ou pega o zero e divide por um valor qualquer, o resultado sempre será 0. 2) Na raiz e no expoente, você não está armazenando o resultado. Por exemplo vc tinha que fazer: `case "x²": memoria = (int) Math.pow(Double.valueOf(memoria),2);` mas daí você também estará perdendo precisão. Dentre vários outros erros...

Comment: Dá uma olhada nessa outra pergunta: [Função ponto na calculadora (números quebrados)](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12953/3117), talvez te ajude..

Comment: O ideal é você ir debugando, linha a linha para entender a lógica que você desenvolveu, daí você vai poder ir corrigindo os erros pouquinho a pouquinho, e melhorando a lógica do seu programa também.

Comment: Calculadora de swing  ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Answer (score 1):

O que deve ter acontecido Edson, é o seguinte:

> **Seleciono numero 1:**
>    O valor de leitura, que era 0, é
>   multiplicado por 10, continuando a ser 0;   O valor de leitura e
>   incrementado em 1, passando a ser 1;   É apresentado o valor 1 na
>   tela.
>  **Seleciono operação "+":**
>    Memoria, contem valor
>   0, é somada com leitura 1, passando a ser 1;   Leitura passa a ser 0; 
>   É apresentado valor "" na tela;
>  **Seleciono numero 2:**
>  O
>   valor de leitura, que era 0, é multiplicado por 10, continuando a ser
>   0;   O valor de leitura e incrementado em 2, passando a ser 2;   É
>   apresentado o valor 2 na tela.
>  **Seleciono operação "=":**
>   Ocorre uma verificação da do termo operacao, "+" é reconhecido;
>   Memoria, valor 1, recebe o valor de leitura, valor 2, como incremento,
>   passando a valer 3;Leitura passa a ter valor 0; É apresentado valor memoria, 3.

Essa operação está certa, mas como o @Math comentou sob a pergunta, vamos realizar o teste de mesa da função de multiplicação:

> **Seleciono numero 1:**
>    O valor de leitura, que era 0, é
>   multiplicado por 10, continuando a ser 0; O valor de leitura e
>   incrementado em 1, passando a ser 1; É apresentado o valor 1 na
>   tela.
>  **Seleciono operação "*":***
>    Memoria, que contem valor 0,
>   tem seu valor multiplicado por leitura, continuando a ser 0; Leitura
>   passa a ter valor 0; É apresentado valor "" na tela;
>  **Seleciono
>   numero 2:**
>    O valor de leitura, que era 0, é multiplicado por 10,
>   continuando a ser 0; O valor de leitura e incrementado em 2, passando
>   a ser 2; É apresentado o valor 2 na tela.
>  **Seleciono operação
>   "=":**
>  Ocorre uma verificação da do termo operacao, "" é
>   reconhecido; Memoria, valor 0, recebe o valor de leitura, 2, para
>   multiplicação; O valor de memoria continua a ser 0; Leitura passa a
>   ter valor 0; É apresentado o valor da memoria, 0, na tela

Eu corrigi o codigo em alguns pontos, e vou repassar para vc. Espero que compreenda.

Em cada actionListener, ao invés de realizar a função dele:

```
memoria /= leitura;
leitura = 0;
```

Eu coloquei como:

```
memoria = leitura;
leitura = 0;
```

Nenhuma mudança drástica, vamos deixar o botão de igual resolver as fórmulas. Nos eventos das botões Raiz e Quadrática, eu coloquei, além da definição de operação da função:

```
memoria = leitura;
btIgual.doClick(0); // Irá invocar o evento click do btIgual;
```

Em cada `case` do botão `btIgual` eu substitui o seu conteudo por:

```
leitura = memoria # leitura;// Substituir # pela função correspondente
display.setText(leitura.toString());
break;
```

Nos `cases` de "√" e "x²" coloquei um valor `Double` auxiliar (valor1, valor2) que recebe a função `Math` correspondente, e, é claro, o `display.setText(valor.toString());`

Agora está funcionando!
Espero que seja de ajuda!