# Problemas com operações em calculadora feita em swing

Tags: java, swing

Preciso fazer uma calculadora, que tenha um funcionamento parecido com a do windows. Estou com problema no momento em que o usuário pode mudar o tipo de operação que ele deseja realizar.

Por exemplo, se ele digitou 10 + e quer mudar o sinal de + para -, ele clica no botão que altera o operador. Porem, para armazenar o meu primeiro numero, utilizo o método `Integer.parseInt(taVisor.getText())` e quando ele aperta algum operador(+,-,*,/), eu começo a armazenar em uma `String`. Ao apertar igual(=), ele verifica o que há na minha `string` e realiza a operação.

Segue abaixo o meu código. O erro que da e esse:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "/"

```
if(evento.getSource()==bSomar){
         //Pega o meu primeiro valor
         a = Integer.parseInt(taVisor.getText());
         //Limpa o meu JtextField
         taVisor.setText("");
         //Adicona o meu sinal de +
         taVisor.setText(taVisor.getText()+"+");   
         taVisor.setFont(new Font("Ibama", 0, 20));
         //parte em estou tendo dificuldade 
         String texto4 = taVisor.getText();
         int qtda = texto4.length();
         boolean retval=true;
         if(retval == texto4.contains("texto4") && qtda==1)
         {
             texto4.replace(texto4,"+");
             //taVisor.setText("");
             taVisor.setFont(new Font("Ibama", 0, 20));
             taVisor.setText(texto4);
         }
      }

      if(evento.getSource()==bIgual)
  {
     texto = taVisor.getText();
     taVisor.setText("");

     boolean retval = true;
     if(retval == texto.contains("+"))//Verifica se a string tem aquele determinado numero de caracter ou se tem aquele caracter
     {
        String nova = texto.replace("+","");//Metodo que substitui um pedaco da string
        int numero = Integer.parseInt(nova);

        int resu = a + numero;

        String texto2 = String.valueOf(resu);

        taVisor.setText(texto2);
        taVisor.setFont(new Font("Ibama", 0, 20));
     }
```

Comment: O Código é muito extenso? Apenas com isso, não deu pra entender bem  a lógica que você está usando para criar uma calculadora.

Comment: Sim, o IDE que eu uso aponta que eu gastei 469 linhas de código. Mas se eu mandar o meu método actionPerformed ajudaria você a entender melhor?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e explique como você está guardando os valores numéricos e dos operadores também.

Comment: Crie uma classe **Expressão** e métodos genéricos para recuperar e editar a expressão. Seus botões vão chamar esses métodos passando o texto editado. Na pratica pense que a lógica fica na classe, seus botões meramente chamam esses métodos passando parâmetros adequados para cada botão

Comment: Retifique a minha explicação espero ter ajudado

Comment: Coloquei mais uma parte do meu codigo para mostrar como faço para pegar o primeiro e o segundo nu8mero, Diego F.

Comment: Tá usando `swing` né?

Comment: Sim estou utilizando @Diego f

Comment: Acho que sua abordagem não está muito boa em relação a como armazenar as informações. Estou impossibilitado agora de mexer na IDE, assim que puder, respondo aqui.

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar resolver como o @jean sugeriu. Aguardo a sua resposta

Comment: Olha, achei algumas respostas que podem te ajudar, minha resposta vai acabar por parecer um "tutorial", e esse tipo de resposta não é recomendado no site, ainda mais quando se tem uma ou mais boas respostas. Veja as que estão em [Calculadora com Interface Gráfica Java](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12471/28595) e [Como fazer operações matemáticas básicas?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40357/28595). Acredito que elas serão bem mais do que você precisa para resolver o problema. :)

Comment: Outro problema é que você está convertendo a `String` do visor, com carateres não-digitos(ou seja, que não são numeros), no caso do erro, o `/`, e o parse vai sempre estourar um `NumberFormatException` toda vez que encontrar um caracter que não conseguir converter para inteiro. tente separar os valores digitados da operação, e se quiser exibir tudo no visor, basta concatena-los. Assim você poderá tratar numeros e operações e variaveis diferentes, evitando o problema de `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Marcos, se a resposta lhe atendeu, seria interessante marcá-la como aceita, assim,servirá de referencia para outros usuarios. :)

Answer (score 5):

Creio que você possa alterar um pouquinho sua lógica, aplicando a dica que o @jean disse nos comentários, também mudando a forma como você valida as operações. Fiz um exemplo para poder explicar melhor na resposta.

## Construção da tela

O print abaixo contem uma tela com dois `JTextField`: um chamado `fieldValorAnterior`, que é menor e fica mais no topo para exibir a conta parcial e outro chamado `fieldValorAtual` logo abaixo, colado no `fieldValorAnterior` que exibirá os números na medida que forem clicados.

Também contém os botões numéricos, ponto flutuante e as operações básicas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Criação dos listeners

Partindo do pressuposto de que seus botões numéricos tem como texto o valor unitário de 0 a 9, você pode fazer um `listener` único para eles, cuja única função é concatenar o valor já existente com o novo valor clicado:

```
class AcaoBotaoNumericoListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String valorAtual = fieldValorAtual.getText();
        fieldValorAtual.setText(valorAtual + btn.getText());
    }
}
```

Basta aplicar aos botões esse `ActionListener`:

```
    this.btn0.addActionListener(new AcaoBotaoNumericoListener());
    // ...
    this.btn9.addActionListener(new AcaoBotaoNumericoListener());
```

Também supondo que tenha botões de operadores cujo texto seja o próprio operador correspondente, basta criar um `actionListener` que vai tratar o conteúdo quando um botão de operação for clicado:

```
class AcaoBotaoOperacaoListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        String valorAtual = fieldValorAtual.getText();
        String valorAnterior = fieldValorAnterior.getText();

        if (!valorAtual.isEmpty() && !valorAnterior.isEmpty()) {
            fieldValorAtual.setText("");
            fieldValorAnterior.setText(efetuarCalculo(valorAnterior, valorAtual) + " " + btn.getText());
        } else if (!valorAtual.isEmpty() && valorAnterior.isEmpty()) {
            fieldValorAtual.setText("");
            fieldValorAnterior.setText(valorAtual + " " + btn.getText());
        } else if (valorAtual.isEmpty() && !valorAnterior.isEmpty()) {
            fieldValorAnterior.setText(valorAnterior.substring(0, valorAnterior.length() - 1) + btn.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Repare que a última condição altera o sinal da operação atual, semelhante a calculadora do Windows. A primeira condição efetuará o cálculo e concatenará com o novo operador clicado, pois ambos os textfields possuem valores, sendo que o `fieldAnterior` sempre será ou vazio ou conterá um número e um sinal separados por espaço(logo explico porque usar espaço). A segunda condição apenas concatenará o valor com o operador e exibirá no `fieldAnterior`.

Para aplicar a ação aos botões:

```
    this.btnAdicao.addActionListener(new AcaoBotaoOperacaoListener());
    this.btnSubtracao.addActionListener(new AcaoBotaoOperacaoListener());
    this.btnMultiplicacao.addActionListener(new AcaoBotaoOperacaoListener());
    this.btnDivisao.addActionListener(new AcaoBotaoOperacaoListener());
```

Agora o botao `=` precisa de um `listener` a parte:

```
this.btnIgual.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String valorAtual = fieldValorAtual.getText();
                String valorAnterior = fieldValorAnterior.getText();
                if (!valorAtual.isEmpty() && !valorAnterior.isEmpty()) {

                    fieldValorAtual.setText(efetuarCalculo(valorAnterior, valorAtual));
                }
            }
        });
```

Note que a conta só será processada se tiver valores em ambos os campos, se essa condição não for atendida, não teremos 2 valores e um sinal para passar para a classe `OperacaoAritmetica`.

## A classe OperacaoAritmetica

Por último, o método responsável por passar esses valores para nossa classe `OperacaoAritmetica`:

```
private String efetuarCalculo(String valorAnterior, String valorAtual) {
    String valores[] = (valorAnterior + " " + valorAtual).split("\\s");

    OperacaoAritmetica operacao = new OperacaoAritmetica(valores[1], Double.parseDouble(valores[0]), Double.parseDouble(valores[2]));
    fieldValorAnterior.setText("");
    String resultado;
    try {
        double res = operacao.calcular();
        resultado = res % 1 == 0 ? Math.round(res) + "" : res + "";
    } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
        resultado = "!ERROR";
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

A condição `res % 1 == 0` verifica se o double retornado é um inteiro exato, e converte para `int`, apenas para não surgir um zero não esperado como em  1 + 3 = 4.0. Usei o `split` para que fosse possível, de forma mais simples, separar os 3 valores(valor 1, valor 2 e operador), por isso foi usado espaço no `listener`  dos botoes de operação.

Para efetuar as operações(e seguindo a ideia já passada nos comentários), você pode criar uma classe que receba o sinal do operador e os dois valores a serem calculados, e nessa classe, implementar todas as 4 operações(cuidado com divisão por zero!) que será a nossa classe `OperacaoAritmetica`:

```
public class OperacaoAritmetica {

    private final String SOMA = "+";
    private final String SUBTRACAO = "-";
    private final String MULTIPLICACAO = "*";
    private final String DIVISAO = "/";

    private String operacao;
    private double valor1;
    private double valor2;

    public OperacaoAritmetica(String sinal, double valor1, double valor2) {

        this.valor1 = valor1;
        this.valor2 = valor2;
        this.operacao = sinal;
    }

    public double calcular() {

        switch (operacao) {
            case SOMA:
                return somar(valor1, valor2);
            case SUBTRACAO:
                return subtrair(valor1, valor2);
            case MULTIPLICACAO:
                return multiplicar(valor1, valor2);
            case DIVISAO:
                return dividir(valor1, valor2);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Operador não é válido");

        }
    }

    private double somar(double valor1, double valor2) {
        return valor1 + valor2;
    }

    private double subtrair(double valor1, double valor2) {
        return valor1 - valor2;
    }

    private double multiplicar(double valor1, double valor2) {
        return valor1 * valor2;
    }

    private double dividir(double valor1, double valor2) {
        if (valor2 == 0) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Não é possivel dividir por zero.");
        }
        return valor1 / valor2;
    }
}
```

Se quiser aprimorar mais ainda com aquele botão de ponto flutuante, basta adicionar um `listener` dessa forma:

```
     this.btnPontoSeparador.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String strValorAtual = fieldValorAtual.getText();
            String strpontoFlutuante = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
            if (!strValorAtual.contains(".") && strValorAtual.isEmpty()) {
                strValorAtual = "0" + strpontoFlutuante;
            } else if (!strValorAtual.contains(".") && !strValorAtual.isEmpty()) {
                strValorAtual += strpontoFlutuante;
            }
            fieldValorAtual.setText(strValorAtual);
        }
    });
```

Se o valor estiver em branco, ele vai preencher com `0.`, caso não esteja, só vai concatenar o ponto mesmo.

E também o botão Limpar:

```
    this.btnLimpar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            fieldValorAnterior.setText("");
            fieldValorAtual.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

---

Com isso já dá para você ter uma noção de como criar uma calculadora bem básica parecida com o windows. Claro que esse exemplo não tratei como recuperar um valor negativo, dentre outras coisas que poderiam ser feitas, mas foi apenas um exemplo, o resto você pode quebrar a cabeça e tentar implementar.

[Neste link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/361e2c3f7032cfeebb11ef219f83a5bc) há um exemplo completo e funcional, que pode ser testado.