# Resultado inesperado ao acionar o botao igual de calculadora

Tags: java, swing

Criei uma calculadora pelo netbeans, que está funcionando, caso seja feita apenas uma operação. Mas caso o usuário clique novamente no `=`(botao igual) o resultado soma o primeiro valor digitado.

Exemplo:
 digitei 1+2
 apertei `=`
 recebo 3

Mas se eu clicar novamente no botao `=`, tenho de resultado 4 e não 5. 
Meu código está da seguinte forma:

Criei essas variáveis na classe principal

```
public class TelaCalculadora extends javax.swing.JFrame {
double numA;
String opera;
double numB;
```

Criei a classe para somar

```
public class soma {
double a;
double b;
double res;
public double somar()
{
   res = a+b;       
   return res;
}
```

A ação quando um botão é acionado

```
private void btn1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    String numeroACalcular;
    numeroACalcular = txtVisor.getText() + btn1.getText();
    txtVisor.setText(numeroACalcular);

}
```

Quando clica no botão "+"

```
private void btnSomaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    opera = "somar";
    numA = Double.parseDouble(txtVisor.getText());
    txtVisor.setText("");
```

e quando clica em "="

```
private void btnResultadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             


    numB = Double.parseDouble(txtVisor.getText());
    if(opera == "somar")
    {
        soma resu = new soma();

            resu.a = numA;
            resu.b = numB;
            resu.somar();
        txtVisor.setText(Double.toString(resu.res));


     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que, ao apertar `=`, você está sobrescrevendo o valor antigo de `numB` em `btnResultadoActionPerformed()`, com o valor atual(no caso, o resultado) e somando com o valor já digitado de `numA`.

A lógica da sua aplicação não está muito boa. A classe `soma` poderia muito bem receber os valores já na sua inicialização e retornar o resultado ao chamar o método `somar()`, não permitindo acesso direto a seus atributos.

Sugiro que dê uma olhada [neste exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120375/28595), pois ele está completo e bastaria pequenas modificações no método de resultado para funcionar como você espera.

De qualquer forma, aqui vai uma solução para o problema do seu código atual:

```
private void btnResultadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             

    numB = Double.parseDouble(txtVisor.getText());
    if(opera == "somar")
    {
        soma resu = new soma();

            resu.a = numA;
            resu.b = numB;
            numA = numB;
            resu.somar();
        txtVisor.setText(Double.toString(resu.res));

 }
```

Comment: Valeu mesmo Diego. vou ver sim.