# Como evitar que uma determinada tecla seja enviada ao programa várias vezes

Tags: java, swing

Estou fazendo uma calculadora para atividade do fim de ano, que até funciona normalmente, desde que não exceda a digitação. Por exemplo, se você realizar a soma de dois números fracionários, ela efetua toda a soma corretamente, mas se, sem querer, digitamos mais de um ponto no botão, ele buga a aplicação, obrigando o usuário a redigitar após realizar a limpeza com o botão CE/C.

exemplo de digitação correta:

> 1.5 + 1.9 = 3.4

exemplo de digitação incorreta:

> 1.5 + 1..9 = não exibe o resultado e trava até limpar o visor.

Quando efetuo operações consecutivas também não da certo. Exemplo:

> 15 -2 -1 = 1.0 ? (12) 58/2*9 = 18.0 (261)

Estou utilizando esse código para o programa realizar a captura do ponto '.' pelo visor um componente de formulário padrão.

```
// pega o caracterer . e exibe . no display;
txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+".");
```

Esse é um problema do meu código, fora isso funciona bem as funções básicas de calculadora.

Em resumo: problemas com digitação duplicada do ponto e efetuando operações consecutivas.

Segue o código:

```
import java.awt.*;

/*   * @author Spencer    */
public class Formulario extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public Formulario() {
    initComponents();
    //setando icone
    /*Toolkit kit = this.getDefaultToolkit();
  Image icone = kit.getImage("/images/calc.png");
  this.setIconImage(icone);*/

    /* ImageIcon icone = new ImageIcon("/images/calc.png");
  this.setIconImage((Image)icone);*/
  /* this.setLocation(300, 100);
   intialize();
}  
private void intialize(){
        this.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("calc.png")));*/
}




 Double operando1, operando2; // catch value
 String operador; //operator

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jButton0 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton30 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton31 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton33 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton34 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton35 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton36 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton37 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton38 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    txtDisplayResult = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Calculadora");
    setResizable(false);

    jButton0.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton0.setText("0");
    jButton0.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 50));
    jButton0.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton0ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("1");
    jButton1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("2");
    jButton2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setText("3");
    jButton3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton4.setText("4");
    jButton4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton5.setText("5");
    jButton5.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton6.setText("6");
    jButton6.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton7.setText("7");
    jButton7.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton7.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton7ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton8.setText("8");
    jButton8.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton8.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton8ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton9.setText("9");
    jButton9.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton9.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton93ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton30.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton30.setText(".");
    jButton30.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton30.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton30ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton31.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton31.setText("=");
    jButton31.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton31ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton33.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton33.setText("/");
    jButton33.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton33.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton33ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton34.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton34.setText("*");
    jButton34.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton34.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton34ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton35.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton35.setText("-");
    jButton35.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton35.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton35ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton36.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton36.setText("+");
    jButton36.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(50, 50));
    jButton36.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton36ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton37.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton37.setText("C");
    jButton37.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 50));
    jButton37.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton37ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton38.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 10)); // NOI18N
    jButton38.setText("CE");
    jButton38.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(30, 50));
    jButton38.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton38ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    txtDisplayResult.setEditable(false);
    txtDisplayResult.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtDisplayResultActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addComponent(txtDisplayResult)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                .addComponent(jButton0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jButton30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 54, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jButton36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addContainerGap(13, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(txtDisplayResult, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jButton38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jButton7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jButton9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addComponent(jButton36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(1, 1, 1)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(2, 2, 2)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton33, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jButton31, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void txtDisplayResultActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                

private void jButton0ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"0"); // pega o número 0 e exibe 0 no display;


}                                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"1"); // pega o número 1 e exibe 1 no display;
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"2"); // pega o número 2 e exibe 2 no display;
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"3"); // pega o número 3 e exibe 3 no display;
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"4"); // pega o número 4 e exibe 4 no display;
}                                        

private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"5"); // pega o número 5 e exibe 5 no display;
}                                        

private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"6"); // pega o número 6 e exibe 6 no display;
}                                        

private void jButton7ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"7"); // pega o número 7 e exibe 7 no display;
}                                        

private void jButton8ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"8"); // pega o número 8 e exibe 8 no display;
}                                        

private void jButton93ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"9"); // pega o número 9 e exibe 9 no display;
}                                         

private void jButton30ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"."); // pega o caracterer . e exibe . no display;
    //break;
}                                         

private void jButton38ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    txtDisplayResult.setText("");// Limpa o visor
}                                         

private void jButton36ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

operando1 = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplayResult.getText());
txtDisplayResult.setText("");
operador ="adic";
// TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

private void jButton35ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //txtDisplayResult.setText(txtDisplayResult.getText()+"-");
    operando1 = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplayResult.getText());
    txtDisplayResult.setText("");
    operador ="subtr";

}                                         

private void jButton31ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          


   // TODO add your handling code here:
  operando2 = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplayResult.getText());
  if (operador =="adic"){
  txtDisplayResult.setText(String.valueOf(operando1+operando2));
  }
  if(operador =="subtr"){
  txtDisplayResult.setText(String.valueOf(operando1-operando2));
  }
  if(operador =="multpl"){
  txtDisplayResult.setText(String.valueOf(operando1*operando2));
  }
  if(operador =="div"){
  txtDisplayResult.setText(String.valueOf(operando1/operando2));
  }

  }                                         

  private void jButton34ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
  // TODO add your handling code here:
  operando1 = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplayResult.getText());
  txtDisplayResult.setText("");
  operador ="multpl";

  }                                         

  private void jButton33ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

  operando1 = Double.parseDouble(txtDisplayResult.getText());
  txtDisplayResult.setText("");
  operador ="div";
  }                                         

  private void jButton37ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     operando1=null;
     operando2=null;
     txtDisplayResult.setText("");

}                                         

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see       http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Formulario.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Formulario.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Formulario.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Formulario.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>
 // Ou JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculadora");
 //Formulario.setTitle("Novo Título");

    //URL url = this.getClass().getResource("imagem.png");
 //Image imagemTitulo = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
 //this.setIconImage(imagemTitulo);

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Formulario().setVisible(true);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Como o código apresentado não é um *[exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve)*, portanto, não dá para executar, e pelo contexto apresentado na pergunta, sugiro você a mudar sua abordagem em torno da calculadora. [*Nesta resposta*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120511/28595) eu explico passo-a-passo como fazer uma calculadora básica, semelhante a do windows.

Ela fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O diferencial é controlar o que é digitado através do uso de teclas específicas para cada função, exatamente como a maioria das calculadoras fazem. Dessa forma, fica mais fácil evitar esse tipo de problema que você vem enfrentando, pois estará restrigindo o que é digitado antes mesmo do usuário digitar. Inclusive nesse exemplo da resposta, há um método somente para o ponto flutuante, para evitar que ele seja digitado mais de uma vez:

```
 this.btnPontoSeparador.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //pega outros valores digitados pelo usuario
        String strValorAtual = fieldValorAtual.getText();
        //pega o ponto(.)
        String strpontoFlutuante = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
        //checa se o usuario não adicionou um ponto 
        //e se não foi digitado nenhum valor
        if (!strValorAtual.contains(".") && strValorAtual.isEmpty()) {
             //adiciona 0. na exibicao
            strValorAtual = "0" + strpontoFlutuante;
        //checa se o usuario não adicionou um ponto 
        //e se já foi digitado algum valor
        } else if (!strValorAtual.contains(".") && !strValorAtual.isEmpty()) {
           //concatena o valor já digitado com o ponto 
           strValorAtual += strpontoFlutuante;
        }
        //altera o valor do campo que exibe a operacao
        fieldValorAtual.setText(strValorAtual);
    }
});
```

Repare que a condição para adicionar um ponto flutuante é o valor atual não possuir outro ponto. Se o valor estiver vazio, um "0" é adicionado junto ao ponto.

A lógica basica para controlar a adição do ponto pode partir desse código acima(caso não queira fazer seguindo o modelo), tem que ser controlado antes da operação ser efetuada.

Outra dica é sempre procurar dar nomes as variáveis que façam referência ao que elas representam no código, o netbeans é uma ótima ferramenta com o construtor de telas, mas é importante essa notação correta, até para manutenção, caso não disponha da IDE para alterar algo no código.

Comment: Seria possível você postar o seu código novamente comentando pelo que vejo só explicou conforme fez noutro post sem maiores detalhes; ???

Comment: @SpencerEkroth qual código?

Comment: this.btnPontoSeparador.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String strValorAtual = fieldValorAtual.getText();
        String strpontoFlutuante = ((JButton) e.getSource()).getText();
        if (!strValorAtual.contains(".") && strValorAtual.isEmpty()) {
            strValorAtual = "0" + strpontoFlutuante;
        } else if (!strValorAtual.contains(".") && !strValorAtual.isEmpty()) {
            strValorAtual += strpontoFlutuante;
        }
        fieldValorAtual.setText(strValorAtual);
    }
});

Comment: por exemplo, terei que criar n variaveis para registrar valor1, valor2 e valor3 e assim por diante

Comment: @SpencerEkroth qual a duvida em especifico? Fica mais você falar do que comentar linha por linha. Talvez lendo a outra resposta linkada até facilite entender melhor esse trecho.

Comment: seria basicamente como vou utilizar o código, precisa adaptar ou só colar no lugar do meu botão de ponto?

Comment: ok, vou procurar a saber o significa criar listeners! grato!

Comment: @SpencerEkroth bom, isso eu não sei te responder, porque como comentei no começo da resposta, não foi apresentado um [mcve] para que fosse testado. Mas a premissa é, inicialmente, trabalhar com apenas valores em strings, e somente na hora de fazer a operação, transformar em inteiros ou floats. Posso comentar as linhas, mas não sei como te explicar como adaptar pro seu código, porque não tenho como testar nele.

Comment: @SpencerEkroth comentei o código. Tente executar a calculadora, o código completo está [**neste link**](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/361e2c3f7032cfeebb11ef219f83a5bc), talvez executando você consiga entender melhor.

Comment: ainda to em dúvida se você realmente entendeu minha questão. com o código que postei então não da para saber o que fazer? Estranho pois as vezes resolvo equações que viram programas? que dados você precisaria a mais @diegofm ?

Comment: @SpencerEkroth como eu já disse na resposta, sem um **[mcve]** não tem como ajudar, seu código não é executável. As dicas que passei na resposta resolvem o problema de outra forma, você pode implementar da forma apresentada ou adaptar, mas se tiver duvida, você precisa fornecer um código que seja executável, senão dificilmente será possivel te ajudar a resolver dentro do seu código.

Comment: Postei o código todo é ainda não serve para o Diego
rezar que outro veja.. rezar!
a sua calculadora bugou antes de digitar qualquer coisa Diego (não marca ele mais, excluiu a conta?) @diegofm seu exemplo não me serviu, nem rodou no netbeans, alias o código acima roda em netbeans então está completo para ele.

Comment: @SpencerEkroth se estiver falando da calculadora da outra resposta, provavelmente é você que não está sabendo usar, pois não só comigo mas várias outras pessoas testaram, me agradeceram pelo exemplo completo e fizeram uso para si. Só na sua IDE que ela bugou, o que não me admira nada, já que o código da pergunta também só executa na sua IDE ;)

Comment: tentei aplicar no meu código mas não deu certo, tudo bem, vou tentar de outra maneira.

Comment: @SpencerEkroth como está seu código atualmente? O da pergunta não é executável porque não tem a inicialização dos componentes(botoes, paineis, etc), você pode copiar o código da pergunta e executar numa classe nova a parte e verá que ele não executa. Se você apresentar o código completo eu posso ver o problema dele.